# Titanium Appcelerator upload video for iphone and android

Tags: mobile, video, upload, titanium

I would like to know which are all format of a video that should be converted when you upload a video on mobile device (Android and Iphone).

This is for a Titanium Appcelerator App.

User should be able upload video from mobile (Android or Iphone) and this should be visible by both device.

In html5 the format of video should be .webm, .ogg and .mp4 (and flv for old browser).

For mobile app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This has already been asked.

> [What video formats are compatible with the assets library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7333671/874257)

Essentially it depends on your device, but I would just stick with H.264 AAC and you will most likely be fine, either way this all depends on your server side to convert the video to a universal format and deliver, this is not so much a mobile / TItanium question.

Comment: Thanks. But other questions it's only for iOS... For Android it's the same?

Comment: ...stick with H.264, android has better video support anyway. ALso, just do all the work on the server side.